# App Store - Managing Availability of Your Apps' Previous Versions

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple release a new feature of the App Store.
The ability for owner of iPhone with non compatible iOS version to download a previous (the last compatible version) of your App.

This can be pretty cool. But unfortunaly I have an old version of my App supporting iOS5 which is not at all supported by my backend. The last version require iOS6 minimum. So any user having iOS5 download an unsupported version of the App.

Apple said that you can delete previous version (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=9182013a):

> If you do not wish to make these versions available, you can manage the availability of your apps' previous versions in the Rights and Pricing section of the Manage Your Apps module in iTunes Connect

But I can't find any link about this in the "Rights and Pricing".

Did anybody successfully deleted previous version of their App?

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT 2013-10-04**: Apple have send an update email to announce the feature ("iTunes Connect: Managing the availability of your app's previous versions.") but still no luck.

Comment: The link you posted references a link to the iTunes Connect user guide. That user guide makes no mention of this feature. There is nothing about this on the "Rights and Pricing" page either. Apple is giving out false info here.

Comment: yep I don't think they actually roll out this feature (remove old version) yet.. but they already allowing to download previous compatible version via the app store... too bad...

Comment: I can't find it either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes connect customer support.

Comment: anyone knows how to FIND these old versions on the app store?

Comment: Nope, I can't find it

Comment: @TommyG I don't think you can manually find this version. You have to go to the App Store with an older version of iOS and the App Store will offer you to download the most recent version supported by your phone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Update for new UI of iTunes Connect (2014).

1) Go to "My Apps" section on iTunes Connect.

[image]

2) Click the app that you want to edit.

[image]

3) On the top menu, click "Pricing"

[image]

4) Click "Manage iCloud download settings for this app" at the bottom of window

[image]

Comment: It's honestly unbelievable that Apple hasn't bothered to update the layout of some of their iTunes Connect pages to match the new style which has been available for months now.... Regardless, good answer +1

Comment: Thank you!!  I went to check on this today and realized that my original answer was terribly outdated.

Answer (score 78):

#### Edit: this is no longer applicable with the new iTunes Connect UI, check out Sars' answer for an updated version

After looking for this page for a few weeks, I finally figured out how to access it:

1) First, go to the [Manage Your Apps](http://www.apple.com/itunes/go/itunesconnect/manageApps) section on iTunes Connect.

2) Click the app that you want to edit.

3) On the right-hand side of the resulting page, click "Rights and Pricing":
[image: Rights and Pricing]

4) Scroll down and click the terribly-named "Manage iCloud download settings for this app":

[image: Manage iCloud download settings]

5) A list of all versions of your application will appear.  You can check a specific version to prevent it from being downloaded due to "a significant usability issue":

[image: Version listing]

Comment: omg! I can't believe I didn't click on this one.. I starred at it for couple of minutes but didn't want to believe that Apple will hide it here.. damn! thx a lot!

Comment: Thanks for this, don't think I would have thought to click that link in step 4!

Comment: You just saved me another 10 minutes looking for that link :)

Comment: ?????!!! OMG.... I cannot believe this. It's so misleading. Think it caused me quite a lot of potential users

Comment: "terribly-named" is an understatement.

Answer (score 15):

It looks like the option has moved again.

1. Go to iTunes Connect and select your app under **My Apps**
2. Select **Pricing and Available** on the left-hand side.
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and expand **Last-Compatible Version Settings**.
4. Click on the **All** link to see the available versions.

[image: app_availability]

Comment: Any idea how long this takes to update for the end users?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the answer, after looking in the iTunes Connect Developer guide. It says:

*You can also indicate a legal issue with your app, including previous versions, from the footer of the “Rights and Pricing” page. Indicate a legal issue with your app by selecting each version of your app that has a legal issue. You cannot select a version of your app that is ready for sale. If the version of your app that is ready for sale has a legal issue, you must submit an update for the app and indicate the legal issue during submission.*

Apparently, indicating a legal issue will prevent users from downloading previous versions.

Comment: thx a lot for your answer too. I did pick up iccir answer more detail. but thx a lot.