# iOS how to upgrade the last compatible version

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

Apple offers the user the option to download an older version of the app that is compatible with the device. if device OS is not compatible with latest version of application. Apple is now displaying a message that allows users to download the "**last compatible version**" of an app. like below

[image]

It is a potential problem for developers if Apple starts re-distributing old versions of apps that their creators thought were safely dead and gone from the App Store. Now that older versions of apps are apparently getting resurrected, so how developer can manager last compatible version of application

(1) How developer can upgrade the last compatible version of application. should he can manage the 2 code base. one is for old OS and second for new OS ? is there any way to submit different binaries to the App Store.

(2) if there is any severe issue with last compatible version of application : how to remove it or upgrade it ?

(3) is there any way to specify that whether old versions of an app are viable.

I think developers should be able to submit different versions for different iterations of iOS so they can ensure the old versions of their app receive what functionality updates they can.

**Link**
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/09/apple-resurrects-old-app-versions-to-run-on-old-ios-hardware/

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade the old versions, but you can remove them so that users can only download your latest one, or nothing.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19193245/15371).

Comment: Is there any provision now to update the last compatible version @Simon ?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the availability of previous versions in itunes connect under Rights and Pricing. sadly there is no way to update previous versions.