# Can we have 2 ios apps with same bundle id target different ios?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, bundle-identifier

Can we have 2 iOS apps with same bundle id target different iOS?

In a scenario, I would like to keep my app supporting iOS 8 and create a new app from scratch supporting only iOS 9 with same bundle id. 
So user on iOS 8 will be able to install existing app and iOS 9 user can install new app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need two separate apps to support both iOS 8 and 9? It's trivial to support both versions in a single app.

Comment: UI is quite different and I intend to support iOS 9 features (stack view, flyovers, spotlight search, etc)  exclusively without worrying about if app is iOS 8 or iOS 9. So keep current app with iOS 8 and new app for iOS9 only users.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, it sounds like what you are looking for is the [latest compatible version](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201377) feature that Apple provides automatically.

If you have an existing app in the App Store that supports iOS 8, and then release an updated version of that app that only supports iOS 9, the previous version will still be available for iOS 8 users to download. When they try to install the app, they will get a message asking if they want to download a compatible version.

Also note that if you want to turn off this feature and not make previous versions available, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19147885/1873374).

Comment: This assumes the OP doesn't wish to continue supporting or updating the version for iOS 8 which may or may not be true.

Answer (score 2):

The Bundle ID must be Unique.

In link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW16

> The product name and company identifier you enter are concatenated to
>   create the default bundle ID using reverse domain name service
>   (reverse DNS) notation. The bundle ID needs to be unique to your app,
>   so it’s important to set the company identifier to a unique string as
>   well.

You just use the same bundle ID when developing your app in different devices. But when you submitting to Apple Store you need to use different bundle ID.

Comment: I cannot confirm, but I think if you submit an App for iOS 8 and download on a device with iOS 8 and after submit an App for iOS 9, the app will continue running on the iPhone with iOS 8, but without the upgrade. New devices with iOS 8  should not find more your app for download. Anyway the project version in the submission will change. I repeat I just think that, I cannot say, the only statement I have is that the bundle ID must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

bundle ids are to be unique, so no

Answer (score 0):

Okay, SO I asked Apple directly. Here is their response:

"Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support
(DTS).

The behavior and resulting limitations you describe are by
design.

If you believe an alternative approach should be considered by
Apple, we encourage you to file an enhancement request with information
on how this design decision impacts you, and what you¹d like to see done
differently.

Although there is no promise that the behavior will be
changed, it is the best way to ensure your thoughts on the matter are
seen by the team responsible for the decision.

While a Technical Support
Incident (TSI) was initially debited from your Apple Developer Program
account for this request, we have assigned a replacement incident back to
your account.

Apple Developer Support
Worldwide Developer Relations"