# new app version release to the App Store keeps old versions available?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, release

We have an available version of the app on the App Store compatible with iOS 7+, iPhone/iPad and we want to release a refactored version of the app that works perfectly on iOS 8 iPhone but with some bugs on iOS 7 or iPad.

**QUESTION:**
Is it possible to release an update only for iOS 8 iPhone users and still allow users with iOS 7 and iPads to download the old version?

Comment: You can release the update only for iOS 8, but not for iOS 8 iPhones, because iPhone apps can be installed on iPads, so iPad users will get the iPhone version instead of the older universal version

Comment: Your iOS7 users will get the old version of the app, after a notification if they want to do so. iOS8 users will get the new version by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You can only keep one version in App Store at one time. However, in your code, you can add version checks, and put different code for iOS 8 and iOS 7 etc. Another way is that you create two separate apps on App Store, one for iOS 7+ and another for iOS 8

However, when you upload your app, Apple saves your older vesrion, as mentioned in link [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160089/how-does-ios-appstore-handle-multiple-version-targeting-different-version-of-ios) and here is how users can [Install the latest compatible version of an app on an earlier version of iOS or OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201377).

Answer (score 0):

check this link its similar your question its help you

link - [App Store - Managing Availability of Your Apps' Previous Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147885/app-store-managing-availability-of-your-apps-previous-versions)

Comment: Yeah I saw that question, but just to be sure. Does that means that users with iOS 7 or iPads will still be able to search and download the app from the App Store and get the last compatible version for their devices?